# Why is a field extension $L:K$ normal if and only if all homomorphisms $L\to \overline{K}$ have the same image?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, definition

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension#Equivalent_conditions_for_normality), given the algebraic extension $L:K$, the following are equivalent:

$a)$ The minimal polynomial over $K$ of every element in $L$ splits in $L$.

$b)$ All homomorphisms $L\to \overline{K}$ have the same image where $\overline{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$.

I have found nothing similar to the above result (equivalence of the conditions) in Stewart's *Galois Theory*, and thus I'm wondering **why are the conditions above equivalent?**

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681686/wikipedias-equivalent-definitions-of-finite-separable-field-extensions) for context. It is probably better not to post each time an equivalence from wikipedia, but to have a look at a book on field theory.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'd be fine with being pointed to a book that does prove the result; furthermore the book I mentioned does treat field theory.

Comment: @DietrichBurde also, the post you link regards _separable_ extensions. Perhaps you meant to link a very similar (now deleted) post I made regarding all the different definitions Wikipedia gives for a normal extension; I deleted said post since the comments made the fair criticism that I was asking multiple questions in one post.

Comment: You have posted several equivalence questions from wikipedia on field theory in the last minutes. I think, this is too much. There are very good books and lecture notes, also online, where all this is proved in detail. So it is producing many duplicates in the end. Therefore I find it better, if you have a look at some book (not Stewart, it seems), but this site has many book recommendations.

Comment: For some equivalence (actually 1. and 4. from your original deleted post, I believe), see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264653/extension-of-a-field-homomorphism-k-alpha-to-overlinek-to-normal-extensi). I suppose I can find more posts.