Let $K \subseteq L \subseteq M$ be algebraic field extensions such that $M/K$ is normal. Show that $[L:K]_s=\#Hom_K(L,M)$.
My attempt: Since $M/K$ is normal, all $K$-homomorphisms $M \to \overline{M}$ can be restricted to $\sigma(M)=M$. Also by definition $[L:K]_s=\#Hom_K(L,\overline{K})$. Since $\overline{M}$ is an algebraic closure of $M$ and $K \subseteq M$, $\overline{M}$ is also an algebraic closure of K. Then we know that there exists a K-isomorphism between $\overline{K}$ and $\overline{M}$.
So if we take any $f \in Hom_K(L,\overline{K})$ then there exists $b \in \overline{M}$ such that $b$ is associated with $f(a)$ for some $a \in L$. Now I think I need to somehow prove that it lands in $M$ using the restriction?
I think I also need to use the fact that since $M/K$ is normal, then $M/L$ is normal too but not sure if it is actually useful. Overall I am stuck and confused

The only step you are missing is to extend a homomorphism from L to K. Then because of the normality of M over K the rest follows as you have already indicated. But that was already discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264653/extension-of-a-field-homomorphism-k-alpha-to-overlinek-to-normal-extensi
